# Unable to copy file to destination

Tags: android, android-studio, video-recording, android-video-record

I'm trying to record a video of the emulator. But I'm getting this error.

> Unable to copy file to destination: C:\Users\Ali The
>   Greatest.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_29_x86.avd\tmp.webm

Are there anyone that had this error before?
Or do you know how to change the default destination?

Comment: Are you able to record the video? or u just have error with the the copy ?

Comment: I can record but I cannot copy.

Comment: Use genemotion it is a good emulator and it has the feature to record the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an AVD, make sure "Use host GPU" is *disabled*.

To take a video recording of your app:

- Start your app as described in Run your App in Debug Mode.
- Click Android  to open the Android DDMS tool window.
- Click Screen Record  on the left side of the Android DDMS tool window.
- Click Start Recording.
- Interact with your app.
- Click Stop Recording.
- Enter a file name for the recording and click OK.

The better option will be that you use [genemotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/176956/how-to-record-your-android-devices-screen-with-android-4.4-kitkat/ use this link it will guide you through your AVD video record.

Comment: i don't see that "use host GPU" option anywhere

Comment: anyone else can't find this option you should be able to look in the extended controls of the emulator itself and find an option to Record and Playback, that worked fine for me and I was able to save the file.