# Unable to copy screen recording of emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm getting the following error.

> Unable to copy file to destination:
>   C:\Users The Greatest.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_26_x86.avd\tmp.webm

Does anyone had the same issue?
How to change the default destination?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to copy file to destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392820/unable-to-copy-file-to-destination)

Comment: I am sorry for that but I was not knowing about this from next time I will keep that in mind. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the duplicate Answer but still as you are a new user I will help you with your answer.

[Duplicate answer Link](https://www.genymotion.com/)

If you are using an AVD, make sure "Use host GPU" is *disabled*.

To take a video recording of your app:

- Start your app as described in Run your App in Debug Mode.
- Click Android  to open the Android DDMS tool window.
- Click Screen Record  on the left side of the Android DDMS tool window.
- Click Start Recording.
- Interact with your app.
- Click Stop Recording.
- Enter a file name for the recording and click OK.

The better option will be that you use [genemotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).

Comment: It is a virtual device same as bluestacks,AVD which is default of Android Studio.Genemotion is really good virtual manager as it consumes less Ram then AVD and bluestacks.

Comment: can't find "use host GPU" option